# How to make UITableView content scroll around a central point

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to figure out how to make the content of a UITableView "centered" around the region contained by the two bars on each side of the screen so that it works on devices of all screen sizes. What I mean by this is:

- The initial state of the view should have the first cell inside that region
- The table view should be able to scroll until the last cell is inside that region
- Cells should not disappear if they're still on screen

I've tried a number of different things around content offsets and insets of the tableview, as well as adjusting the table view's frame, but I inevitably either get the insets wrong or end up with cells disappearing before they're off screen.

I'm wondering if either this is the wrong approach altogether, or I just have the incorrect combination of settings.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
//In viewDidLoad, etc...:
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let inset = (self.tableView.frame.size.height - 44) / 2.0 // Figure out your bar size here

    self.tableView.contentInset.top = inset
    self.tableView.contentInset.bottom = inset

    let path = NSIndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) as IndexPath

    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: path, at: .middle, animated: false)
}
```